# Xpath grabbing wrong text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to grab the price from this page: https://www.eq3.com/ca/en/product/cjv8cke45026q01786nahx8uf/lighting/lighting/pendant-lamps/nelson-bell-bubble-pendant-lamp?cjv49km02036401865sece5be=cjv49km0503650186hc90zvnq

It should be getting `$1,376.15 CAD` however I'm getting some other text from the page and sometimes it doesn't work at all and gives me:

```
 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Here's my code:

```
DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)

XPATH = '//*[@id="app"]/main/div/div/section[1]/div/div[3]/div/span[1]'

url = 'https://www.eq3.com/ca/en/product/cjv8cke45026q01786nahx8uf/lighting/lighting/pendant-lamps/nelson-bell-bubble-pendant-lamp?cjv49km02036401865sece5be=cjv49km0503650186hc90zvnq'

driver.get(url)


price = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, XPATH)))

print(price)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that out:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
url = "https://www.eq3.com/ca/en/product/cjv8cke45026q01786nahx8uf/lighting/lighting/pendant-lamps/nelson-bell-bubble-pendant-lamp?cjv49km02036401865sece5be=cjv49km0503650186hc90zvnq"
driver.get(url)
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,'MuiTypography-root') and contains(@class,'MuiTypography-h3')][1]")))
text = el.text
print(text)
driver.quit()
```